# I want to know what the 'it' means

Tags: meaning

> Others, more creative solutions to the congestion problem are to increase tax on fuel so that **it** is more expensive, or make people pay to travel on certain roads such as in the centre of a city or on a motorway.

I want to know what the word "it" means in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"It" refers to the fuel (though it could also be applied to tax)... obviously nothing else in the first part of the sentence can be "expensive".